# Only handling tree will expand but not tree selection in JTree - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am doing lazy loading for my app. I want a node to load only user click to it's icon. The point is i don't know that node have it's children or not.My temporary solution is to define a node having children then loading them based on selection event, i don't use tree will expand event for lazy loading. Is there any ways for me to just implement treeWillExpand event. You can reference in [TreeWillExpanListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html) and [TreeExpandEventDemo2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/TreeExpandEventDemo2Project/src/events/TreeExpandEventDemo2.java).

Answer (score 2):

```
// Have a tree with some unexpanded root items
// When an item is expanded, add some children
tree.addListener(new Tree.ExpandListener() {

    public void nodeExpand(ExpandEvent event) {
        // No children for the first node
        if (!hasChildren(event.getItemId())) {
            tree.setChildrenAllowed(event.getItemId(), false);

        } else {
            // Add a few new child nodes to the expanded node

                tree.addItem(childId);
                tree.setParent(childId, event.getItemId());


        }
    }
});
```

you can implement hasChildren to find the child based on tree node being expanded and then find child and add

Comment: Thanks for your supporting. I still feel confuse about the selection and expand event, i mean as i saw in another example. The parent node have already knew it's children and had it's symbol to expand, when user click to expand the node implement lazy loading.
I think when user click a node, firstly they do selection event then if the node has the expanding symbol, they click to do lazy loading cause i don't add them. In my situation, the node know about it's children, which is a list customMuatableNode but it doesn't have the expanding symbol. Could you clarify these actions more clearly.

Comment: You can add the icon for the leaf node using DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = 
        new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon); // here use the plus icon for leaf nodes too. And on expansion/click change it back to expanded icon
tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

Comment: In my tree, each node has it's icon. Your solution is very helpful.

Comment: I think you are a experiential java developer. I have my an swing app with a large of tree nodes about more 100.000 nodes. Although i divide jtree into 4 layers and also do lazy loading as you see, it slightly improve performance. Do you any suggestion for me to speed up my app?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by performance here? Loading of tree nodes which are in thousands and tens of thousands is taking time, or fetching/preparing data for the tree nodes that is taking time?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I mean preparing data is taking time, hence i use lazy loading to delay loading. As i understand the fewer children the node have, the faster the app load. My app divides into 4 layers. The last layer has the most number of nodes almost 100.000 nodes.

Comment: Not sure if I can comment properly on performance without actually running the code, but if indeed loading of 1000000... nodes is an issue, you can load nodes in "chunks". e.g first load 100, or 1000 nodes and then add "loadMore" and then can load nodes using "pagination" or scroll model.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks for your help.